# How to get list of cars with a specific ID of wheel?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following code snippet :

```
CREATE TYPE ModeleRoue (nom VARCHAR2(10) );
CREATE TYPE ModeleMoteur (nom VARCHAR2(10) );
CREATE TYPE ModeleVoiture (nom VARCHAR2(50) );
CREATE TABLE EnsModeleVoiture OF ModeleVoiture;
CREATE TABLE EnsModeleMoteur OF ModeleMoteur;
CREATE TABLE EnsModeleRoue OF ModeleRoue;
CREATE TYPE ModeleRoue (nom VARCHAR2(10) );
CREATE TYPE ModeleMoteur (nom VARCHAR2(10) );
CREATE TYPE ModeleVoiture (nom VARCHAR2(50) );
CREATE TABLE EnsModeleVoiture OF ModeleVoiture;
CREATE TABLE EnsModeleMoteur OF ModeleMoteur;
CREATE TABLE EnsModeleRoue OF ModeleRoue;
```

I want to get the Voitures having number of Roue = 554 :

```
SELECT v.numero FROM ensvoiture v
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM v.roues r WHERE r.numero=554);
```

What is the difference of using the table in the EXISTS subquery directly in the WHERE clause?

```
SELECT v.numero FROM ensvoiture v
WHERE  v.roues.numero =554;
```

Comment: Your first query doesn't make sense. The `exists` is not joining with your `ensvoiture` table, so if there is at least one record in your `roues` table with `numero=554`, it will return the whole `ensvoiture` table. So definitely, you must use your second query.

Comment: @JaimeDrq So if I want to correct the 1st query : 
SELECT v.numero FROM ensvoiture v
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM roues r WHERE v.roues. numero = r.numero AND r.numero=554);

Comment: Why do you create an OBJECT type for a simple type? `CREATE TABLE EnsModeleVoiture OF VARCHAR2(10)` should do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to write your first query would be:

```
SELECT v.numero FROM ensvoiture v
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM v.roues r WHERE r.numero=v.numero and r.numero=554);
```

This query, written this way, is doubtfully usefull, because it seems that you want to filter your `ensvoiture` table for those numbers equal to 554. Therefore, the exists would be unnecesary and you could use just your second query.

```
SELECT v.* FROM ensvoiture v
WHERE  v.numero =554;
```

This doesn't mean that both queries will return the same data, because if there is no any `r.numero=554`, your first query will return nothing. The second one will keep returning data even whether the `roues` table doesn't have any `numero=554`.

Comment: I can't still get the second query behaviour

Comment: Indeed, your second query "as is" is also doubtfully usefull, because it will return 554 n times. You must choose in the `SELECT` part those attributes which you are interested in. Try initially replacing  `SELECT v.numero` by `SELECT v.*` ¿Is it your problem?

Comment: BTW, I have replaced the second query because it has a little copy/paste typo. Is the `numero` field present in your `ensvoiture` table? If not so, we are talking about a different problem.

Comment: But I needed to check if : WHERE v.roues.numero =554 is applicable as the WHERE condition you mentioned refers to the number of the Voiture not the Roue

Comment: Your problem is different then. You must modify your first query with something like this... `SELECT v.numero FROM ensvoiture v
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM v.roues r WHERE r.[your_join_field]=v.[your_join_field] and r.numero=554);` You could replace the `exist` by `join` sintax. I don't know what is your joining field between these two tables (not explained in your question)